# Pacific islands where you can see natives who don't wear clothes?

Tags: factoids, culture, islands, nudism, oceania

Jacque Fresco [once mentioned](http://youtu.be/kj21LpHUqnM?t=43s) that he find naked people in Tuomoto when he was living in South Pacific for 1 year. But that was in the 50's, so a lot has probably changed.

He said that they don't have any clothes ad were naked and that they do look into the eyes when they speak with each other and not on the breasts or ass etc.

I don't agree with him on this subject 100%, because even male macaques were excited if they were shown bums of female macaques in heat. But I agree that "scarcity" creates a lot of fetish behavior etc ;)

Anyway, my question is what are some islands where you can find native people who don't wear any clothes at all.

Comment: have you seen naked people wearing clothes? More seriously, your request sounds condescending and more like sexual tourism.

Comment: @Vince No, I need that info for a project I am working on.

Comment: If someone wanted to visit a place where most women wore burqas, would that be seen as "sexual tourism"?

Comment: Ah so now I see, they must be naked, *and* they must be wearing no clothes, but it's fine if they're wearing accessories such as belts, jewelery, and penis protectors?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about anthropology rather than travel.

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, accesories are OK.

Comment: I agree with the anthropology categorisation, and even if we would accept the anthropologic travel, this is a travel site, not a forum to debate animal sexual attraction. The question could be looking for a non-naturist nudist island, period.

Comment: The OP has a real question about a real problem at the end of the question. The stuff about why he wants to go to places where people don't wear clothes may be a little waffling, but if he didn't explain why he wants to do so, I bet the first response would be "Why do you want to do this?".

Comment: There will still naked tribes deep in the Amazon pretty recently, possibly even now. But they're now being protected I think from tourists as well as missionaries. You'd need special permission and/or permits to go there. And some of them do not like outsiders (which is completely unrelated to their traditional dress).

Comment: You know, there are some anthropologiest who write that people in USA, when they talk, look into the eyes and not on breast or ass. It's easy to make such false assumptions if you know only the surface of the culture. Anyway, this is heavy off-topic.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: The OP has a real question about human behaviour in places where people are traditionally naked. That's an interesting anthropology question. He hasn't asked any question about travelling. Perhaps you and the OP could edit and re-word the question.

Comment: @hippietrail the only reason they're still not corrupted into wearing clothes is the fact that missionaries aren't allowed to indoctrinate them... IMO way too much is made about the whole nudity thing, which is in itself the cause of it being sexualised. Visit your average nude beach, except for some gawkers and cruising homosexuals, pretty much nobody's there for sexual gratification. Same would be true for such tribes (with the gawkers being the tourists and missionaries...).

Comment: Dude you're preaching to the choir. In some places where people were traditionally naked or the women topless they have covered up not because of missionary activity but because of gawking foreigners. The Zoe in the Amazon were still naked when a Spanish documentary was made in a recent decade and I believe the Piraha were naked when they didn't have outside visitors but I wonder if that's changed since the government installed some infrastructure recently. Anyway I would totally vote for this on anthropology.SE but this SE is for travel.

Comment: Note: There is [a proposal for an anthropology.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49575/anthropology) and a question on this topic would probably be possible on [skeptics.SE under their "anthropology" tag](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anthropology).

Comment: What about nudist colonies that happen to have locals?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking this on Travel SE **I assume you also would want to visit such an island**. I think I have found exactly what you are looking for, with the only downside, that it is **not a Pacific island but in Europe**:

## Île du Levant

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Ele_du_Levant) some 90% of the island is military and thus off-limits but the rest can easily be visited.

> Being nude is allowed (and expected) everywhere on the public area of the island, except in the immediate vicinity of the harbour and on the village square. On these locations, it is formally necessary to wear what the French jokingly call French: le minimum, often a pareo or a string. In conformance with the relaxed atmosphere of the island, this rule is not really enforced, but generally well observed.

So I am sure you will be able to find there *"native people who don't wear any clothes at all"* even though I do have to admit that some of these people might not be natives but tourists like you.

Some more info can be found [here](http://www.hyeres-tourism.co.uk/en-hyeres/le-levant) and [here](http://www.iledulevant.com.fr/en/) [warning: some pictures there are NSFW] and on the [French Wikivoyage](https://fr.wikivoyage.org/wiki/%C3%8Ele_du_Levant).

When visiting you should stick to the etiquette (beyond clothing, or rather the absence of such) as indicated e.g. [here](http://gocalifornia.about.com/cs/clothingoptional/a/nudebeachguide.htm)

> - Gawking is impolite. In fact, it's rude to stare, no matter where you are and no matter how the other person is dressed (or isn't). A nude beach isn't a peep show and if you're looking for a thrill, go somewhere else.
> - Ask for people's consent before taking their photograph. This is also true no matter where you are, but especially if they're nude.

but also [here](http://nomadsworld.com/articles/global/top-ten-tips-for-nudist-beach-etiquette). This is in line with what you cite that *"they don't have any clothes ad were naked and that they do look into the eyes when they speak with each other and not on the breasts or ass etc."*

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that anything that is easy to visit is less likely to have indigenous tribes or populations of any size that would not have started to wear clothes. Exceptions are the spring break populations in the USA etc.

So in order to answer your question, I would suggest you to take a look at a list that has all the most likely candidates, namely the [un-contacted peoples of the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontacted_peoples). What kind of clothes they wear is of course sometimes hard to say because, well they have not been contacted. But the chances that they wear Adidas sweatpants at least is very low.

Comment: give me cargo (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_Cult) (and yes, even the extreme case of crashing aircraft or ships leading to a cargo cult could be considered contact I know).

Answer (score 1):

All hunter/gather tribes that is uncontacted is usually naked at first. It's not until shortly after they done the loincloths.
On the island of Yap (Micronesia) you may find some people in regular clothing but the clothing of choice is loincloths. Wrap around types that provide more coverage then the amazon style. Besides exposing a lot of thigh is considered indecent. But woman walk around topless and think nothing of it.

Comment: Note that there are enormous [ethical questions](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2015/07/23/do-the-worlds-uncontacted-tribes-deserve-to-be-left-alone/) around going around and visiting uncontacted (or mostly uncontacted) tribes. Consult your local institutional review board, do not pass go, do not collect $200.

Comment: in fact, most countries containing areas where such tribes exist or are expected to exist severely restrict travel and any other activity in those areas, often including disallowing scientific expeditions from entering for the very real reason that those scientists often end up destroying the very tribes they set out to study and protect.

Comment: Well, most uncontacted today, I suppose, are in regions where being naked is comfortable.  But if there are any more than 4000 kilometers from the equator, I suspect they invented clothing ages ago.